# Install elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

Thank you for the beautiful work you guys have done with this OS, I'm having a problem, I followed all the steps on you site to try to install the USB I made when downloading the OS, I chose the 64 bit version and I tried to install it on a Acer AO1-431-C8G8 computer with Windows 10 pre installed, I tried to install a single boot overwriting Windows as I complete dislike Windows and I bought this computer with the sole purpose of turning into a Linux machine.
Can you please if possible send me a step by step instructions of the installation if possible, or could it be possible that when I made the USB I messed up something.

Comment: Did something go wrong with the installation? If so, what was the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The setup is very simple and easy

Anyway, here's how to install it

This is the first screen you'll get

[image: eOS]

-Click "Install elementary"

-"Continue"

-Check "Erase disk and install elementary" then press "Install now"

-"Continue"

-Choose your location then "Continue"

-Choose your keyboard layout then press "Continue"

-Set your username and password then "Continue"

-It gonna take few minutes installing and you'll be ready to go

-Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

So, you didn't even start installing it? If so, you should create a bootable USB (using Rufus, for example), then reboot your computer, and select your USB as a boot device. From there, elementary OS will boot, and you should follow the instructions on the installer to install it.